# MySQL: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE gives Truncated incorrect date value error

Tags: mysql

My query should be simple...

```
INSERT INTO email_final_list
(E_mail, Title, First_Name, Last_Name, ZIP_Code, AddMethod, Update_Date, Status)
SELECT
    DISTINCT E_mail,
    Title,
    First_Name,
    Last_Name,
    ZIP_Code,
    CASE WHEN AddMethod IS NULL THEN 'Opera' ELSE 1 END as AddMethod,
    Update_Date,
    Status
FROM guest_profiles
WHERE E_mail NOT LIKE '' AND ifnull(Update_Date, '') <> '' AND STR_TO_DATE(Update_Date,'%d/%m/%Y') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    email_final_list.E_mail = guest_profiles.E_mail,
    email_final_list.Title = guest_profiles.Title,
    email_final_list.First_Name = guest_profiles.First_Name,
    email_final_list.Last_Name = guest_profiles.Last_Name,
    email_final_list.ZIP_Code = guest_profiles.ZIP_Code,
    email_final_list.AddMethod = guest_profiles.AddMethod,
    email_final_list.Status = guest_profiles.Status,
    email_final_list.Update_Date = guest_profiles.Update_Date
```

The 'Update Date' fields on BOTH tables are VarChar (no idea why, but this cannot be changed). But when I run this, it returns

```
[Err] 1292 - Truncated incorrect date value: '11/4/2013 00:00:00'
```

The really odd thing is that if I run the SELECT part on it's own, I don't get any results.

The database was inherited so can't be changed - the schema & names are all over the place, but unfortunately, I have to work with it.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong here?

Thanks

Edit: the EXACT code is

```
INSERT INTO `email-final-list`
(`E-mail`, Title, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `ZIP Code`, AddMethod, `Update Date`, `Status`)
SELECT
    DISTINCT `E-mail`,
    Title,
    `First Name`,
    `Last Name`,
    `ZIP Code`,
    CASE WHEN AddMethod IS NULL THEN 'Opera' ELSE 1 END as AddMethod,
    `Update Date`,
    `Status`
FROM `guest-profiles`
WHERE `E-mail` NOT LIKE '' AND ifnull(`Update Date`, '') <> '' AND STR_TO_DATE(`Update Date`,'%d/%m/%Y') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `email-final-list`.`E-mail` = `guest-profiles`.`E-mail`,
    `email-final-list`.Title = `guest-profiles`.Title,
    `email-final-list`.`First Name` = `guest-profiles`.`First Name`,
    `email-final-list`.`Last Name` = `guest-profiles`.`Last Name`,
    `email-final-list`.`ZIP Code` = `guest-profiles`.`ZIP Code`,
    `email-final-list`.AddMethod = `guest-profiles`.AddMethod,
    `email-final-list`.`Status` = `guest-profiles`.`Status`,
    `email-final-list`.`Update Date` = `guest-profiles`.`Update Date`
```

But I cannot change the database fields AT ALL.

Comment: Is it because you are using and underscore `_` instead of a minus sign `-` in this clause `STR_TO_DATE(Update_Date,'%d/%m/%Y') > CURDATE() _ INTERVAL 5 DAY`

Comment: Oops - that was a typo. Now updated.

Comment: How do you make typo in a copy/paste? And if its not a copy/paste what else is not as it is in the real code?

Comment: `E_mail NOT LIKE ''` should really be `E_mail != ''`

Comment: The inherited database has hyphens in field names - to avoid being told to re-name all the fields, I replaced them with underscores. That's it.

Comment: As @RiggsFolly points out, we suspect this not to be your exact code. 1292 is usually a warning and not an error.

Comment: Could this be that one of the dates stored is in a format that `str_to_date()` is not understanding? i.e. it is not stored in `'%d/%m/%Y'` format

Comment: Storing dates in VARCHAR is of course a nightmare senario, looks like someone dropped you right in it!

Comment: This error can also be because you are trying to compare a number against a string! So it looks likely that `STR_TO_DATE(`Update Date`,'%d/%m/%Y') > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 5 DAY` is picking up a date it cannot deals with properly

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but if I run the query part & set the day interval to 3650 (to get all records), I don't get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be sending a `datetime` while your field is a `date`. Probably you should change your table structure from `date` to `datetime`.

Comment: I can't change the database structure!

Comment: OP said dates were all stored as VARCHAR!

Comment: that doesn't matter. can ignore the time part try `select STR_TO_DATE('11/4/2013 00:00:00','%d/%m/%Y')`